# How to regulate a Li-ion battery voltage to a constant 12 V?

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, lithium-ion, stability

I don't know if it even makes sense to regulate a 12 V that's supplied to an 100 0W inverter via lithium-ion battery pack because I need the voltage to be stable even when the battery voltage starts falling down.

So the question is: do I need a regulator for this case?

If yes, what is the most efficient way to regulate it?

Comment: It might make more sense if designing to use a higher voltage, lower current supply.  24V is half the current, so those high-current traces could be less than half as wide at twice the voltage.  Then two battery packs can be used, extending run-time to slightly better than 2x and improving overall efficiency.  48 Volts = even better.

Comment: I didn't think of increasing the voltage(although it is obvious) but I will consider this of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically one would use an inverter designed to operate with an input voltage range that includes the desired part of the battery discharge curve and then cut off the battery when it drops too low (to protect the battery from damage).

The inverter, if properly designed, should be able to produce a stable output voltage (and frequency) even though the input voltage changes (within limits).

Comment: so you mean it depends on the inverter not the batteries?

Comment: It is a functionality that *can* be built into the inverter with very little loss in efficiency and little or no added complexity. Regulating the input voltage with a separate SMPS would greatly increase the complexity and losses.

Comment: I thought like using a normal regulator with a current follower MOSFET

Comment: You could do that but you might not like the losses and heatsink required. Work the numbers.